# How to condition github action task to run on specific platform type?

Tags: github-actions

I do want to run a specific task (run) on github action only on a specific platform (linux).

How can I do this? Consider that the matrix is complex and I do not want to manually add a variable to achieve this.

Example:

```
- run: echo this is linux
  if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'
```

This fails if platform is another type of Ubuntu. Is there a way to test if is generic linux?

Comment: Use `if: contains(matrix.os, 'ubuntu')`?